# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'append' of null

Tags: javascript, graph, plotly

I recreated the ploytly.js dropdown graph here:

https://plot.ly/javascript/dropdowns/#bind-dropdown-events-to-plotlyjs-charts

I copy and pasted the code in my app and it worked perfectly.

Now I just want to duplicate the graph and put it below the original.  Here is the html:

```
<div class="showcase__section" id="bubble">
  <div class="spacer --small"></div>
  <div id="bubbleplots">
    <div class="bubbleplot" data-num="0">
      <div class="plot" id="plotdiv"></div>
      <div class="control-row">
        Country: <select class="countrydata">
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="showcase__section" id="bubble">
  <div class="spacer --small"></div>
  <div id="bubbleplots">
    <div class="bubbleplot" data-num="0">
      <div class="plot1" id="plotdiv1"></div>
      <div class="control-row">
        Country: <select class="countrydata1">
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I changed 3 of the divs so the javascript can tell them apart.

Below is the javascript.  Again, I changed the names of the some the variables of the second graph.  Otherwise, the javascript of the first and second graph is identical.

The first graph shows up perfectly in my app, but there's an issue with the second graph.  The second graph shows up, and the data is correct on the graph and the popup menu shows up but with no country names.  I console.log('currentOption1') of the second graph three separate times.
The first two times the console returns as expected, but the third time it shows 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'append' of null'.  So the problem lies with

```
selector.appendChild(currentOption1);
```

Again,

```
selector.appendChild(currentOption);
```

works perfectly with the first graph.

So currentOption1 is null.  Why, and how do I fix it?

Here is a link to the [two graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogzdq.jpg)

```
Plotly.d3.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/gapminderDataFiveYear.csv', function(err, rows){

    function unpack(rows, key) {
        return rows.map(function(row) { return row[key]; });
    }

var allCountryNames = unpack(rows, 'country'),
    allYear = unpack(rows, 'year'),
    allGdp = unpack(rows, 'gdpPercap'),
    listofCountries = [],
    currentCountry,
    currentGdp = [],
    currentYear = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < allCountryNames.length; i++ ){
    if (listofCountries.indexOf(allCountryNames[i]) === -1 ){
      listofCountries.push(allCountryNames[i]);
    }
  }

  function getCountryData(chosenCountry) {
    currentGdp = [];
    currentYear = [];
    for (var i = 0 ; i < allCountryNames.length ; i++){
      if ( allCountryNames[i] === chosenCountry ) {
        currentGdp.push(allGdp[i]);
        currentYear.push(allYear[i]);
      }
    }
  };

// Default Country Data
setBubblePlot('Afghanistan');

function setBubblePlot(chosenCountry) {
    getCountryData(chosenCountry);

    var trace1 = {
      x: currentYear,
      y: currentGdp,
      mode: 'lines+markers',
      marker: {
        size: 12,
        opacity: 0.5
      }
    };

var data = [trace1];

var layout = {
  title: 'GDP per cap according to Country<br>'+ chosenCountry + ' GDP'
};

    Plotly.newPlot('plotdiv', data, layout);
};

var innerContainer = document.querySelector('[data-num="0"'),
    plotEl = innerContainer.querySelector('.plot'),
    countrySelector = innerContainer.querySelector('.countrydata');

function assignOptions(textArray, selector) {
  for (var i = 0; i < textArray.length;  i++) {
      var currentOption = document.createElement('option');
      currentOption.text = textArray[i];
      selector.appendChild(currentOption);
  }
}

assignOptions(listofCountries, countrySelector);

function updateCountry(){
    setBubblePlot(countrySelector.value);
}

countrySelector.addEventListener('change', updateCountry, false);
 });


Plotly.d3.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/gapminderDataFiveYear.csv', function(err, rows){

    function unpack(rows, key) {
         return rows.map(function(row) { return row[key]; });
    }

var allCountryNames = unpack(rows, 'country'),
    allYear = unpack(rows, 'year'),
    allGdp = unpack(rows, 'gdpPercap'),
    listofCountries = [],
    currentCountry,
    currentGdp = [],
    currentYear = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < allCountryNames.length; i++ ){
    if (listofCountries.indexOf(allCountryNames[i]) === -1 ){
      listofCountries.push(allCountryNames[i]);
    }
  }

  function getCountryData(chosenCountry) {
    currentGdp = [];
    currentYear = [];
    for (var i = 0 ; i < allCountryNames.length ; i++){
       if ( allCountryNames[i] === chosenCountry ) {
        currentGdp.push(allGdp[i]);
        currentYear.push(allYear[i]);
      }
    }
  };

// Default Country Data
setBubblePlot('Brazil');

function setBubblePlot(chosenCountry) {
    getCountryData(chosenCountry);

    var trace1 = {
       x: currentYear,
       y: currentGdp,
      mode: 'lines+markers',
      marker: {
        size: 12,
        opacity: 0.5
      }
    };

    var data = [trace1];

    var layout = {
      title: 'GDP per cap according to Country<br>'+ chosenCountry + ' GDP'
    };

    Plotly.newPlot('plotdiv1', data, layout);
};

var innerContainer = document.querySelector('[data-num="0"'),
    plotEl = innerContainer.querySelector('.plot1'),
    countrySelector = innerContainer.querySelector('.countrydata1');

function assignOptions(textArray, selector) {
  for (var i = 0; i < textArray.length;  i++) {
      var currentOption1 = document.createElement('option');
        console.log('currentOption1')
      currentOption1.text = textArray[i];
      console.log('currentOption1')
      selector.appendChild(currentOption1);
      console.log('currentOption1')
  }
}

 assignOptions(listofCountries, countrySelector);

function updateCountry(){
    setBubblePlot(countrySelector.value);
}

countrySelector.addEventListener('change', updateCountry, false);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var innerContainer = document.querySelector('[data-num="0"')
```

calls the first dropdown box so I changed it to

```
var innerContainer = document.getElementById('bubble1')
```

and it retrieved the correct data from the second set of identical data after I created the 'bubble1' id in the html to differentiate the two.